# debug rmd file using data in global environment

Tags: r, debugging, r-markdown, preload

Update:2019.11.11

My Workflow:

1.Write and debug .RMD file chunk by chunk,read sample data into GE(global environment).

2.Use "knit to word", read sample data again, whatever `cache=T or F`.(How to use sample data in GE?)

3.Using rmarkdown::render from shiny (select new data file), read data with using `cache=F` (otherwise,the data will not updated along with selection params).  So I cache the new data into GE using `<<-`.

4.Repeat step 2 when erro found in step 3 with a new selected data, it reads the new data again.(How to use new data in GE?)

5.Or Repeat step1, it can use the new data in GE.

6.Goto step3, it reads new data again.(It is a feature).

I haven't found a way to debug .RMD file from shiny,(I tried breakpoints and browser()), so I have to repeat step 2\3\4 many times with long reading times, because I am unable to reuse the data in global environment.

---

I want to debug the style of output docx file using rmarkdown codes. Each time when I using the “knit to word” menu, it will read the data again which will spend a long time. But if I preload the data and comment the “read” codes, it will be a error.
I find the function “knit2pandoc”, but it can’t     output an expected results.
So my question is how to debug rmd file using global data without reread the data again and again.

test.rmd

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  word_document: default
  html_document: default
---
## R Markdown

```{r cars}
library(flextable)
dt<-cars # comment this line codes
flextable(dt)
```
````

Input codes in Console

```
dt <- cars
```

Errors with that line codes commented:

```
Error in object[[i]]: object of type ‘closure’ is not subsettable 
Calls:......
```

Debug codes in Console

```
library(knit)
knit2pandoc(“test.rmd”,to=“docx”)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/huK7d.png

Comment: You could try to cache the chunk where you read the data. Read more about it here: https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/ and https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#cache

Comment: Thank you, I updated the situation of my workflow.